# Relationship between thread and runnable object

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

What is the relation between the thread spawned and the `Runnable` object which contains the `run` method. Once the threads are spawned does it matter which `Runnable` object which created the thread? Also the thread that is spawned is it an object?

Comment: Everything is an object except primitives. What is the driving force behind this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on this kind of stuff all over the web..

Runnable extends thread.

To make a thread **object** ->

```
Thread objThread = new Thread(anyobject of type class that implements runnable);
```

Then

```
Thread.start();
```

will internally called the `run()` method.

Comment: yes. I know but I am curious to know if the thread created is an object or a process. If its an object then the default thread the main thread is also an object

Comment: If you create a thread you are creating a new object.. so yes it is an object